# Why does this `.new` constructor auto increment a field?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to port some Dart code to another language but I'm a little confused by the `.new` constructor.

Given this class:

```dart
class DynamicTreeNode {
  final int id;
  DynamicTreeNode(this.id);
}
```

and this simple `main` function:

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  List<DynamicTreeNode> _nodes = List<DynamicTreeNode>.generate(
    16,
    DynamicTreeNode.new,
  );
}
```

I can see in the debugger that each instance of `DynamicTreeNode` is given an incrementing `id` value matching the index in the `List`:

[image: Debugger]

Can someone explain what is happening here? I thought the call to new would fail as the unnamed (and only constructor) requires an `int` to be passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the [`List.generate`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) constructor we can see that the signature is

```
List<E>.generate(

    int length,
    E generator(
        int index
    ),
    {bool growable = true}

)
```

The `generator` parameter — in your case `DynamicTreeNode.new` — is a function that takes the position in the list it is generated into as an argument and returns the type of element of the list. So the first `DynamicTreeNode` in the list will be generated by `DynamicTreeNode.new(0)`, the second one as `DynamicTreeNode.new(1)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with dart at all, but it looks like you're passing the `.new` function itself, and the `.generate` function on `List<T>` will construct an object under the hood by calling the `.new` function with an incrementing integer.

In JavaScript, that would look like this:

```js
class DynamicTreeNode {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

const generate = (len, constructor) => new Array(len).fill(0).map((_, idx) => new constructor(idx));

function main() {
  const _nodes = generate(16, DynamicTreeNode);
  console.log(_nodes);
}

main();
```